# Retrieving the data from MySql, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables one is for Questions, And one is for Options. 
All the questions will be saved on Questions Table.

Question table:

```
id | questions                                       | created_on 
1  | Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup?| 13-09-2016
2  | Who won the FiFA world cup?                     | 13-09-2019
```

Options table:

```
id | question_id | option_text
1  | 1           | Pakistan
2  | 1           | India
3  | 1           | Australia
4  | 1           | Srilanka
5  | 2           | Canada
6  | 2           | Russia
7  | 2           | Germany
8  | 2           | France
```

This is the table:

I expect the json response in following format:

```
[
{
    "question": "Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 1,
    "options":[ 
    {"option_text": "Pakistan"},
    {"option_text": "India"},
    {"option_text": "Australia"},
    {"option_text": "Srilanka"}
    ]
},
{
    "question": "Who won the FiFA world cup?",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 2,
    "options":[ 
    {"option_text": "Canada"},
    {"option_text": "Russia"},
    {"option_text": "Germany"},
    {"option_text": "France"}
    ]
}
]
```

But in my following SQL query

```
    $records = DB::table('tbl_questions')
        ->where('created_on', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->leftJoin('tbl_options', 'tbl_options.question_id', '=', 'tbl_questions.id')->get();
```

Returns following response:

```
[
 {
     "question": "Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 1,
     "option_text": "Pakistan"

 },
 {
   "question": "Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 1,
    "option_text": "India"
 },
 {
 "question": "Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 1,       
    "option_text": "Australia"
 },
 {
    "question": "Who is the world champianship on 2016 World cup",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 1,
    "option_text": "Srilanka"
  },
  {
   "question": "Who won the FiFA world cup?",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 2,
    "option_text": "Canada",
  },
  {
    "question": "Who won the FiFA world cup?",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 2,
    "option_text": "Russia",
    },
    {
    "question": "Who won the FiFA world cup?",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 2,
    "option_text": "Germany",
    },
    {
    "question": "Who won the FiFA world cup?",
    "created_on": "2019-09-13",
    "question_id": 2,
    "option_text": "France"
    }
 ]
```

Anybody can help me for the expected json response. Helps will be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use ```One to Many``` relationships. Which means a question could have multiple options and to achieve that your system should have 3 tables like, ```questions```, ```options```, ```question_options``` . Last table will be used as pivot for questions and options table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your model and add options as a relationship.

```
Class Question extends Model
{
    public function Options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
    }
}
```

In your controller do this.

```
public function questions()
{
    return Question::with('options')->where('created_on', '=', date('Y-m-d')->get();
}
```

Comment: I am new to Php laravel. Could you please explain Which is Model? and which is keyword?

Comment: I am getting... with not found on $this.

Comment: it says Cannot instantiate abstract class PhpOption\Option in file

Comment: You have to put Options() function in your model

Comment: you need to include the option model with Use App\Option or where you saved it and offcourse create an options model.

Answer (score 2):

Please do try using Eloquent Relationships instead.
[Refer Documentation Link Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Using this we can define certain relationships among models, there are a different types therein. In your case its one to many relation, as for one question there are many options 
First you will need to define the relation and in the model as shown below and 
In the controller you will get the result using following -

```
$result = Questions::with('options')->get()
```

This will be your **Question Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questions extends Model
{

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Options');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to Php laravel. Could you please explain me little more.

Comment: Using this we can define certain relationships among models, there are a different types therein. In your case its one to many relation, as for **one question there are many options**   First you will need to define the relation and in the model and the get the result as - $result = QuestionsModel::with('options')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Create one hasMany relationship in Question model. like this

`public function options()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Option');
 }`

and use with function in your query to retrieve option like this

```
$records = DB::table('tbl_questions')
    ->where('created_on', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->with('options')
    ->get();
```

Comment: tried. Not working. here options is option table name correct?

Comment: @Noorul no it's laravel relationship method name.

Comment: I am getting... with not found on $this

Comment: put options function inside your model.